# Try using the rtl8192eu driver on Toradex IM8XMP as an access point

Tags: linux, wifi, driver, embedded-linux, dongle

I'm trying to use the RTL8192eu driver as an access point on Toradex IMX8MP.

The problem is that I have to go through systemctl start hostapd to see the access point in the available networks:

```
torizon@chronos-4972825b:~$ systemctl status hostapd
● hostapd.service - Hostapd IEEE 802.11 AP, IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP/RADIUS Authenticator
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/hostapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

```
torizon@chronos-4972825b:~$ systemctl status hostapd
● hostapd.service - Hostapd IEEE 802.11 AP, IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP/RADIUS Authenticator
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/hostapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-07-18 14:48:59 UTC; 38s ago
    Process: 2383 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd /etc/hostapd.conf -P /run/hostapd.pid -B (code=exited>
   Main PID: 2384 (hostapd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 3189)
     Memory: 1.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/hostapd.service
             └─2384 /usr/sbin/hostapd /etc/hostapd.conf -P /run/hostapd.pid -B

Jul 18 14:48:58 chronos-4972825b systemd[1]: Starting Hostapd IEEE 802.11 AP, IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/>
Jul 18 14:48:58 chronos-4972825b hostapd[2383]: Configuration file: /etc/hostapd.conf
Jul 18 14:48:59 chronos-4972825b hostapd[2383]: Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr 1e:c2:c7:72:09:8c>
Jul 18 14:48:59 chronos-4972825b hostapd[2383]: wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
Jul 18 14:48:59 chronos-4972825b hostapd[2383]: wlan0: AP-ENABLED
Jul 18 14:48:59 chronos-4972825b systemd[1]: Started Hostapd IEEE 802.11 AP, IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/E>
lines 1-16/16 (END)...skipping...
● hostapd.service - Hostapd IEEE 802.11 AP, IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP/RADIUS Authenticator
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/hostapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-07-18 14:48:59 UTC; 38s ago
    Process: 2383 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/hostapd /etc/hostapd.conf -P /run/hostapd.pid -B (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2384 (hostapd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 3189)
     Memory: 1.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/hostapd.service
             └─2384 /usr/sbin/hostapd /etc/hostapd.conf -P /run/hostapd.pid -B

Jul 18 14:48:58 chronos-4972825b systemd[1]: Starting Hostapd IEEE 802.11 AP, IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP/RADIUS Authenticator...
Jul 18 14:48:58 chronos-4972825b hostapd[2383]: Configuration file: /etc/hostapd.conf
Jul 18 14:48:59 chronos-4972825b hostapd[2383]: Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr 1e:c2:c7:72:09:8c and ssid "test"
Jul 18 14:48:59 chronos-4972825b hostapd[2383]: wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
Jul 18 14:48:59 chronos-4972825b hostapd[2383]: wlan0: AP-ENABLED
Jul 18 14:48:59 chronos-4972825b systemd[1]: Started Hostapd IEEE 802.11 AP, IEEE 802.1X/WPA/WPA2/EAP/RADIUS Authenticator.
```

However, when I'm connect to the wifi I don't have internet.

If you have an idea, I thank you in advance for your reply.

Also, when I connect to the access point, the card reboots itself.

I expect to be able to connect to the Internet.

Comment: You seem to have listed quite a number of issues - I'd suggest to concentrate on only 1 at a time. `The problem is that I have to go through systemctl start hostapd` - why is it a problem? Can't you enable it to start automatically upon boot? Or does it error out during autostart? If it does, what's the error?